# django-admin dbshell CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path

Tags: python, django, django-database

I use two sqlite databases in my django project . One for default and another for customer_data.

This is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
},

'customers': {
    'NAME': 'customer_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'USER': 'db2',
    'PASSWORD': 'db2password'
}
```

}

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['theapp.routers.CustomerRouter',]
```

This is my routers.py

class CustomerRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'customer':
            return 'customer_data'
        return None

```
def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'customer':
        return 'customer_data'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'customer' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'customer':
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'customer':
        return db == 'customer_data'
    return None
```

Comment: The error says "You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed". So, have you tried [installing it](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) yet?

Comment: I thought Sqlite come with django default. Do I have to install another one cos I use two sqlite databases?

Comment: Python comes with the `sqlite3` module, so you don't have to install anything to use the `django.db.backends.sqlite3` database backend. However the `dbshell` command tries to use the sqlite3 CLI, which doesn't appear to be installed for you. It's normally installed on Linux/Mac, so I guess you're on Windows. Each sqlite3 database is in a separate file. You only need to install the sqlite3 CLI once.

Comment: Thanks. I use Linux.  Now I just installed sqlite3 and run it >>.database it only shows customer_data.db. I was wondering where is my default database?

Comment: That's a separate question really. Django should create the default database in `'db.sqlite3'` (because of your `DATABASES['default']['name']` setting) when you run migrate. If that doesn't happen, then perhaps there's a problem with your router. For example it looks like your router will never return `True` for the default db.

Comment: Really thank u. I only write routers.py showing above only for the custmer_data. Do I have to write for default too?

Comment: We’ve gone off topic, that’s a completely different question.

Comment: Thank u anyway .

Answer (score 4):

As the error message `You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed` suggests, you need to install the sqlite3 cli in order to use the `dbshell` command.