# VS Code does not see sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I am building a website using Django and wanted to inspect my database using command: `python manage.py dbshell` however surprisingly I got `CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.` I am using VS Code for my project and got the error in command prompt terminal of VS Code.

I am saying surprisingly because I have already created my models  before with commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate.` These commands also don't work right now.

It is impossible that sqlite3 is not installed because python installs it inherently. I assume PATH variable is also not an issue as I added it and can run sqlite3 outside of VS Code if I open command prompt from the start menu of windows.

What can be the reason of this corruption/problem and how can I fix it ?

*This is screenshot of start menu command prompt* :
[image: Start menu command prompt]
*This is screenshot of VS Code* :
[image: VS Code]

Comment: Python installation does not automatically install the sqlite3 command.  The problem is your path.  Your command prompt's path is different from your VSCode path, and the path to sqlite3.exe is not there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How can I add path to sqlite3.exe to VSCode path?

Comment: @hcsaral -Please refer to the content of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950645/django-admin-dbshell-commanderror-you-appear-not-to-have-the-sqlite3-program) to download a sqlite3.exe file from the sqlite official website and install it to the local disk (C:\Windwos\System32).